# Post-commit hook failed (exit code 255) with no output

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

So I'm trying to make a pre-commit hook for svn but the error `Post-commit hook failed (exit code 255) with no output` keeps coming out. I have browse the other question but don't really understand as I am new to svn.

```
#!/bin/sh
# POST-COMMIT HOOK

REPOS=$1
REV=$2
UUID=`svnlook uuid $REPOS`
URL=http://XXXXXXXXXXX:8080/subversion/${UUID}/notifyCommit?rev=$REV
echo $URL

/usr/bin/curl \
 -v \
 --connect-timeout 5\
 --header "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" \
 --data "`svnlook changed --revision $REV $REPOS`" \
$URL
```

Comment: Start by specifying the full path to `svnlook` when you execute it. How scripts run in an empty environment, so there's no `$PATH` for it to look in.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by chmod my post commit file. Turns out it didn't have permission to execute